# Same font, character spacing and line-height but different results

Tags: html, css

The introduction of @font-face in CSS3 allows web designers to use fonts that look the same across all browsers. That is what I thought until trying it out with the following code in [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yxGWT/1/):

**HTML**:

```
<div>
    The_Quick_Brown<br>
    Fox_Jumps_Over<br>
    The_Lazy_Dog
</div>
```

**CSS**:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Open Sans';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: url('http://themes.googleusercontent.com/static/fonts/opensans/v6/cJZKeOuBrn4kERxqtaUH3T8E0i7KZn-EPnyo3HZu7kw.woff') format('woff');
}

div {
    display: block;
    width: 496px;
    height: 86px;
    font-size: 1.3em;
    font-family: 'Open Sans';
    font-style: normal;
    margin: 0;
    border: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background: cyan;
    letter-spacing: 1.44em;
    line-height: 1.44;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

[image: Firefox 12.0]

This is the view from Firefox 12.0. Take note of the partially obscured 'o' in 'brown', the position of 'g' in 'dog' and the underscore '_' at the bottom edge.

[image: Google Chrome 19.0]

This is the view from Google Chrome 19.0.

Despite explicitly setting `letter-spacing` and `line-height` for the same font, why are the results still different?

Comment: It may be more related to rendering of the div and then the contents inside it. *MAYBE*

Comment: The font rendering will depend on how the browser feels like rendering it. And because of that browsers also render the `letter-space` differently. I have noticed that when using `monospace` fonts in FF you will not get the desired results because FF doesn't support `monospace` fonts properly. Could be a similar thing here?

Comment: It appears the characters are a bit more tall and narrow in Chrome than in FF.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is correct. The problem is your browser/ Each browser (browser rendering engine to be specific) renders contents in a different manner. You may not get the exact same output from each browser all the time. The features and all other blings might be the same but it is almost always a different story in terms of rendering a web page.

Answer (score 0):

we don't have nothing much to do in this issue. Its totally depends on the browser's text rendering engine. Every single browser renders text differently.